# create-react-app webpack 2 || 3 Peer Dep issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to update firebase to 4.5.0 but it is giving me PEER DEP error:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2 || 3
```

How do update webpack?

my webpack is **webpack@1.14.0**

> Note: I am using create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make some changes in your webpack.config.js file because there are some major changes in webpack2. For example, module.loaders is now module.rules. You can take help from the webpack's website. Here is that specific link [Migrating to webpack2](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/)

Comment: Please read the **Note** at end of question. I am using `create-react-app`. That means i should not modify **webpack.config.js** file.

Comment: You can modify that. This will help:
https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a

But I recommend that you eject the app. And customize according to your needs.